# any ruby wrapper for lame encoders out there that has good documentation?

Tags: ruby, lame

I have checked out http://rubyforge.org/projects/lame-encoder/

but the problem is it isn't documented(i don't even know how to use it) and it wrecks my gemfile because it requires rspec 0.5.0 which is totally old.

I would just like to encode wav files to mp3s using ruby so if there are other alternatives, please do suggest some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just running lame something like this?

```
def mp3_encode(wavefile)
    system("lame -V2 -f " + wavefile + " " + wavefile.gsub("wav", "mp3"))
end
```

Comment: well i was hoping i wouldn't need to do that but thanks :) follow up question though, this assumes the machine has lame installed, and will this work for windows/unix lame installations?

Comment: i'll accept this as it did point me at the right direction. thanks

Comment: On Windows you probably have to add lame to the `Path`.